# Using || double-pipe inside of a START CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, parallel-processing, nested

Similar to

```
CMD /C Do.cmd || goto :error
```

I‘m trying to use the double-pipe as part of a command within a start statement, but i don‘t manage to nest it correctly. I.e. the "on-error" statement runs only when the start-command itself fails (i.e. as part of the caller script). But i want the started sub-process to run it when the main do.cmd fails.

Here is what i‘m trying to run:

```
( 
      start „parallelproc1“ cmd /c do.cmd || echo 1 > pperror.log
      start „parallelproc2“ cmd /c do.cmd || echo 1 > pperror.log
    ) | pause
    if exist pperror.log goto :error
    Continue.cmd
```

Basically, i only want to continue, if none of the do.cmd of the parallelproc failed. Can i not use || inside start?

Comment: A lot wrong here. You need to get your quoting correct to start off with, but as far as `||` goes, it does not work the way you used it. You need to use it as conditional statement, but to better understand it, I would need to see what `do.cmd` does. We typically also `call` batch files and not `start` them.

Comment: Do.cmd exits with 0 if successfull or with 1/errorlevel otherwise.. as soon as i m home tonight i‘ll extend the example accordingly & fix the formatting

Comment: That is what I thought. So have a look at @stephan's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the parser how to "group" the parts of the command line:

```
start "parallelproc1" cmd /c "do.cmd || echo 1 > pperror.log"
```

See `cmd /?`, especially the part beginning with:

> If /C or /K i specified, then the remainder of the command line after
>   the switch is processed as a command line, ...

Another way to tell the parser to pass poison characters like `|` and `>` to the subprocess is to escape them:

```
start "parallelproc1" cmd /c do.cmd ^|^| echo 1 ^> pperror.log
```

(personally, I prefer the first one, but there might be reasons to use the second one in some special cases)

Comment: „Grouping“ i.e. enclosing it in quotes worked perfectly, thx :)  i did try escaping it before but totally missed escaping the >-sign! (I‘m also using various variables in the real code, which made troubleshooting the escape-approach an absolute pain)